# Conditionally show Alert using onbeforeunload in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, onbeforeunload

I want to show alert popup conditionally when I am in Edit mode. I tried using `HostListener` but it appears even when we are not in edit mode so I want to disable `onbeforeunload` event conditionally. For now All I know is onbeforeunload will help me provide alert box but it will appear for all the cases. The Code I am using is :

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload',['$event'])
  defaultConfirmation(event : any): void {
    console.log(this.initiateEdit)
    if(this.initiateEdit) return true;
    else return false;
  }
```

Comment: Generally, in Angular you use a [Guard](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#candeactivate-handling-unsaved-changes)

Comment: It's not about routing. It's about accidently refreshing the page while we are in edit mode.  @Eliseo